# Probability of getting $n$ tails in a row

Tags: probability

Imagine we have an unusual coin. Probability of getting a tail is equal to $p \in [0, 1]$. Of course that means that probability of getting a head is equal to $q = 1-p \in [0, 1]$.
Let's define a random variable $X$
$$X = \text{the amount of throws until getting n tails in a row}$$
I am to calculate $\mathbb{E}(X)$, where $\mathbb{E}$ is the expected value. How can it be found? I would appreciate any tips or hints.

Comment: @drhab  I think your proposed solution was nearly correct.  To get $k$ tails in a row I must first get $k-1$ tails in a row.  So, we go out $\mu_{k-1}$ turns and toss. either I win or I restart.  If we restart I then expect $1+\mu_{k-1}+\mu_k$ tosses (including the $1+\mu_{k-1}$ tosses I have already done).  Thus $\mu_k=p(1+\mu_{k-1})+q(1+\mu_{k-1}+\mu_k)$.  No?

Comment: @lulu That gives $\mu_k=p^{-1}+\mu_{k-1}$ and seems not to agree with what I found now after some struggling. On the other hand I have not the guts to say it is wrong, since it looks good. Good chance that my revised is answer is wrong also.

Comment: @drhab  Does it?  I get $\mu_k=\mu_{k-1}+1+q\mu_k\implies p\mu_k=\mu_{k-1}+1$ Thus $\mu_k=\frac 1p\times (1+\mu_{k-1})$  Which seems to harmonize with your new answer.

Comment: @lulu Ah, yes. I misunderstood at first hand because in my new answer $\mu_k$ is defined on a different way than in my first answer, $\mu_n$ and $\mu_0$ somehow "switched" of meaning.

Comment: @drhab  I think your first answer (correctly modified) is the way to go.  Comparatively clear.

Comment: @lulu Why not you writing that answer? The essential idea that repairs mine is yours.

Comment: @drhab Because it's yours.   All I did was add back a term you dropped.

Comment: @lulu Okay then, I will make an addendum within a while. Thank you for attending me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that we are in status $k$ if our last $k$ throws ended up in tail and the (eventual) throw before this sequence of tails is not a tail.

Let $\mu_k$ denote the expectation of the number of throws needed to arrive at $n$ tails in a row if we are in status $k$.

Then $\mu_n=0$ and to be found is $\mu_0$.

For $k=0,1,2,\dots n-1$ we have:$$\mu_{k}=p(1+\mu_{k+1})+q(1+\mu_0)=1+p\mu_{k+1}+q\mu_0$$

So we have the following equalities:

- $\mu_0=1+p\mu_1+q\mu_0$ so that $\mu_0=\frac1p+\mu_1$
- $\mu_1=1+p\mu_2+q\mu_0=1+p\mu_2+\frac{q}p+q\mu_1$ so that $\mu_1=\frac1p+\frac q{p^2}+\mu_2=\frac1{p^2}+\mu_2$

This makes us suspect that $\mu_k=\sum_{i=k+1}^np^{-i}$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n$ and substitution in $(1)$  confirms that conjecture.

The the outcome is:$$\mathbb EX=\sum_{i=1}^np^{-i}$$

---

**addendum**:

Another way to look at it is this:

Let $\nu_k$ denote the expectation of the number of throws needed to achieve exactly $k$ tails in a row.

Then $\nu_0=0$ and to be found is $\nu_n$.

Now let it be that after $X$ steps we have a consecutive row of exactly $k-1$ tails. Then by throwing tails we need $X+1$ throws to get a consecutive row of exactly $k$ tails. By throwing heads we come back in start position and from there $X+1+Y$ steps will be needed to get a consecutive row of exactly $k$ tails. This with $\mathbb EX=\nu_{k-1}$ and $\mathbb EY=\nu_{k}$ hence giving the equality:$$\nu_k=p(1+\nu_{k-1})+q(1+\nu_{k-1}+\nu_k)$$or shorter:$$p\nu_k=1+\nu_{k-1}$$

This leads easily to:$$\nu_k=\sum_{i=1}^kp^{-i}\text{ for }k=1,2,\dots$$so that: $$\nu_n=\sum_{i=1}^np^{-i}$$

---

Credit for the second solution (definitely the most elegant one) goes to @lulu.

I was on a path that was nice but not completely okay.

Someone attended me on that (thank you @saulspatz).

Then someone said to me: take the original path, but with an adaption (thank you @lulu).

Comment: I did this too, but on reflection, I don't think it's right.  If we toss a tail, we can't say we just need $n-1$ tails in a row.  If the next toss is heads, we're back to needing $n$ tails in a row.

Comment: @saulspatz You are correct. I will delete this within some minutes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [finite-state absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain).  The state is the number of consecutive tails we have tossed so far.  We start in state $0$ and the absorbing state is $n$.  If we are in state $k<n$ then we transition to state $k+1$ with probability $p$ and we transition to state $0$ with probability $q,$ so that the first column on the matrix $Q$ described in the wiki has $q$ in every position, and the entries on the superdiagonal are all $p.$

You need to figure out $(I-Q)^{-1}$